# Unique ID for list.ParentWeb.GetFolder method

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007

I have a SharePoint custom list with folders. Each folder has items inside it.
The folder names are Folder1, Folder2, Folder3 ....So on.

I want to get each folder by its unique Id in a iteration.

```
 SPFolder folder = list.ParentWeb.GetFolder(new Guid("{xxxxx-xxxx-xxxxxx-xxxx}"));
```

How can I find the unique ID for each and every folder? i.e the GUID Defined in the brackets.

Thank you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really get why you want to fetch the folders based on the guid, if you can fetch the guid you probably already have the folder.

I would typically solve this using extensions. Here is a variant of what you are looking for

```
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Herlitz.Common.Extensions
{
    public static class SPListItemCollectionExtensions
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Get a folder by it's guid
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="spListItemCollection"></param>
        /// <param name="uniqueId"></param>
        /// <returns>SPFolder or Null</returns>
        public static SPFolder GetFolderByGuid(this SPListItemCollection spListItemCollection, Guid uniqueId)
        {
            var firstOrDefault = spListItemCollection.Cast<SPListItem>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.UniqueId.Equals(uniqueId));
            return firstOrDefault != null ? firstOrDefault.Folder : null;
        }
    }
}
```

And to query

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(spSiteUrl))
{
    using (SPWeb web = site.RootWeb)
    {
        SPList myList = web.GetList("thelist");
        SPFolder theFolder = myList.Folders.GetFolderByGuid(new Guid("{c4819d5f-276e-4923-81cd-a3b014f1db6g}"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

SPFolder has UniqueId property. It is Guid that you can use as parameter in SPWeb.GetFolder method.